# Call WCF from a plain html page (on same domain)

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf

I have a Windows Service that host a WCF service.

My small test program (a Windows Console) can call this WCf just fine (the service is just returning a date and time).

**But I cannot get it to work on my index.html page! Why?**

Everything runs on my machine. No webserver is involved.

Here is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>TEST</title></head>
<script Language="JavaScript">
    function test() {
        var url = 'http://localhost:80/TestService'
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url+'/GetCurrentDateTime');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                alert('Response=' + xhr.responseText);
            }
            else {
                alert('Request failed. Returned status=' + xhr.status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="test()"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open file in Chrome and press the button I get this error:

index.html:24 GET http://localhost/TestService/GetCurrentDateTime 404 (Not Found)
test @ index.html:24
onclick @ index.html:8
index.html:1 Failed to load http://localhost/TestService/GetCurrentDateTime: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Here is how the console host the WCf service:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:80/TestService");
_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CommonService), uri);
_serviceHost.Open();
```

Here is how my test program calls it (this works just fine):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:80/TestService");
var binding = GetDefaultHttpBinding();
var factory = new ChannelFactory<ICommonContract>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
ICommonContract service = factory.CreateChannel();

// Call WCF service - this works fine
var dateTime = service.GetCurrentDateTime();
Console.WriteLine("Datetime: {0}", dateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Everything runs on my machine. No webserver is involved.*

You are mistaken my friend, the url http://localhost:80/TestService
Creates an HTTP request to your Web server. 
**404 (Not Found) test**:because your end of body tag must be after script tag.

```
</div>
<script Language="JavaScript">
//rest of script here
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Failed to load http://localhost/TestService/GetCurrentDateTime: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to let a user agent gain permission to access selected resources from a server on a different origin (domain) than the site currently in use.
For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts.
To overcome this, you have to tell the browser or give permission to access the cross origin domain resources but decorating the Web. Config file with below configuration.

```
   <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <!-- Enable Cross Domain AJAX calls -->
                <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I have corrected the script location (also in the question text). Still same error. Regarding cross origin. I only work on localhost. No other domains. I have added more info about the WCF. It works fine from console app. I use the http protocol - but I still believe that no web server is involved.

Comment: He you put the above configuration in your Web. Config file?.Do you still get 404 test error?

Comment: I do not have a web.config file - nor a web application. But thanks anyway because your snippet got me google this page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2016/08/31/wcf-cors-support-for-self-hosted-wcf-rest-service/ that I need to investigate.